# Capture facebook like/unlike button click event

Tags: facebook, events, click

What is the way of capturing facebook like/unlike click event nowadays? I have old jquery project(no angular or react). I put iframe tag on my web site to render fb like button.

this is not triggering

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response) {
    alert('You liked the URL: ' + response);
});
```

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2017/11/07/changes-developer-offerings/

Answer (score 0):

> **edge.create and edge.remove JS SDK Events:** These Events will no longer
> be accessible. As an alternative, you can use our Webhooks and be
> notified every time someone likes one of your Facebook Pages.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2017/11/07/changes-developer-offerings/

Web Hooks: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks/

Btw, just to be safe: You are not allowed to reward users for liking something, or gate content behind likes.